# Force execution in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am actually trying to modify a *Makefile* and I want at the end of this makefile add a command that will be run even if the rest of the make fails and I would also like to know if it would be possible to run this command even if the user hits `ctrl + c`.
I searched a bit on the web but couldn't find an answer to my question.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is basically not possible to define something in a makefile that will always be run as the very last thing.

The best I can suggest is that you create a wrapper script that people invoke instead of `make`, and that the wrapper script run the command you want after `make` exits.  The script can capture SIGINT (^C) even.

If you really must do it with make the only way to do it is create a "wrapper makefile" that essentially invokes a sub-make on the real makefile to do the work, then can do more things when that sub-make finishes.  There's no way to catch SIGINT in this situation.  This is also complicated because there's not really any such thing as "perfect forwarding" in makefiles, so getting the makefile wrapper to behave identically as when there is no wrapper is tricky or even impossible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a command every time make is called you can call the `shell` function:

```
DUMMY := $(shell myCommand &)
```

Put it at the beginning of the Makefile such that it is one of the first things make will do. Normally stopping make with `CTRL-C`, unless you are super fast and hit `CTRL-C` before make executed the command, should not stop the child process.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately the command should be executed at the very end of the Makefile :/

Comment: There is not really a "begin" and an "end" in a Makefile. A Makefile explains how to do things. Which one is done first and which one is done last is not as simple as first or last in the Makefile. The last thing in the Makefile can very well be done first and the first thing can be done last. Things can even be done in parallel. Can you please explain a bit better after what, exactly, your final command shall be executed?

Comment: the command will actually be a python script which will change the source code of the program to facilitate the development. In fact the python script is called twice (but different arguments and so different functionalities), once at the "beginning" of the makefile which is important for the compilation and once at the end in order to facilitate users during development

Comment: You cannot solve these beginning/end issues just by putting something at the  beginning (end) of the Makefile. Makefile are not shell scripts, this is not how it works. You need to declare what you want to do at the beginning as a prerequisite of everything else and you must declare what you want to do at the end as a target that has everything else as a prerequisite. But then things will go wrong if any intermediate rule fails...